# Some Files Disappeared After Git Stash

Tags: git

I'm working on directory. I've made some modifications since my last commit. And i want to ignore all this modifications (which after my last commit) . In shortly, i want to turn back my last commit . I've accidentally execute wrong command and i have execute this:

```
git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 46dbc13 Ayarlar activity geri butonu
HEAD is now at 46dbc13 Ayarlar activity geri butonu
```

After this, most of my files (my all image files) gone away. But they were exist in my last commit (#46dbc13). They are deleted after my stash.  I have no idea. I have executed `git stash apply` but nothing changed.

Can you tell me what's happening ?

Comment: `git stash` does not delete anything which is in the last commit (the `HEAD` at the time of the call to `git stash`), so you must have done something else.  Does `git log` list 46dbc13 as your tip commit? If yes, then just do `git reset --hard` -- this will repopulate both the index and the work tree with the contents of `HEAD`, which is (supposedly) 46dbc13. This has to bring your beleived-to-be-deleted files back. If it won't, you're misunderstanding the situation or not telling us enough detail.

Answer (score 7):

`git stash` is a mechanism to "put your changes aside". I see it used most frequently when you're in the middle of writing new functionality but have to switch to something of a higher priority.

If you'd like to see a list of your stashes, you can go with `git stash list` and see something similar to the following:

```
git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 46dbc13 Ayarlar activity geri butonu
```

If you would like to apply your changes, you're going to have to either go with one of the two following commands:

`Pop`: this will pop the top stash off your stack

```
git stash pop
```

'Apply': this will apply a given stash. If your `git stash list` has just the single stash (like is given above), you can use this. If you have multiple stashes, you will need to apply the specific stash you wish to apply.

```
git stash apply stash@{0}
```

Comment: As i said, i'm not trying to stash my work. I want to reset. I did stash accidentally, and my files gone away.

Comment: So use `git stash apply stash@{0}` and files should come back :)

Comment: `git reset` is another topic all together. Perhaps you could edit the question and title to express your intentions more clearly. So instead of "I did this and it didn't turn out like I wanted", try "I'd like to do this... how can I go about it"

Answer (score 1):

I found answer in same time with @kostix .

```
git reset --hard 46dbc13
```

solved my all problem. I found this command from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/556169

Answer (score 0):

It has been 5 years since the question was asked but maybe this answer will be beneficial for contemporary members.

I am writing this answer for those who have faced the same issue and use (or would use) NetBeans IDE.

**SOLUTION:**
*In NetBeans, click on your project name, then from the main menu choose Team => History => Revert Deleted.
Wait a little and NetBeans will list previously deleted files. Select the ones you need and click OK.*

That's it, no need to struggle with any command, thanks to NetBeans for this practical solution!